# jquery and rails 3 asset pipeline

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

Just a quick question as I am trying to clarify my understanding of the asset pipeline.

So if i have

```
   //= require jquery_ujs
```

in my application.js file, does this mean that rails will call the neccesary library for me or do i still need to put the actual libary in my assets/javascripts directory.

I have read some documentation but the theory behind it all isnt quite there

Any help/advice appreciated

Comment: I have found out the answer for this:

When you add // require jquery_ui rails is actually dynamically calling the js file for this.

so for example if I had jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js in my assets/javascripts directory I could remove this as I am already calling it in my application.js file via the asset pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the answer for this: When you add // require jquery_ui rails is actually dynamically calling the js file for this. so for example if I had jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js in my assets/javascripts directory I could remove this as I am already calling it in my application.js file via the asset pipelin